# Manipulating Visio shapes using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, visio

I am trying to manipulate Visio shapes using Excel VBA using the following code it is not generating errors but its not running

```
Sub ShapeControl()
Dim shp As Visio.Shape
Dim mst As Master
Dim Verdana_ID As Integer
Dim ActiveDoc As Object
Dim ActivePage As Object
Dim VisioApp As Object


Set ActiveDoc = GetObject("C:\Users\z028317\Desktop\Architecutre Flowchart.vsdm")
Verdana_ID = ActiveDoc.Fonts.Item("Verdana").ID
Set ActivePage = ActiveDoc.Pages("Page-1")
  
' iterate all shapes per page
For Each shp In ActivePage.Shapes

    ' declare parent master for current shape
    Set mst = shp.Master
    ' Process only shapes that have parent master-shape
    If Not (mst Is Nothing) Then
        ' Connector Properties Settings
        If mst.Name = "Dynamic connector" Then shp.Cells("LineColor").Formula = "RGB(255,192,0)": shp.Cells("LineWeight").Formula = "1.0 pt"
        ' Process Box Properties Settings
        If mst.Name = "Process" Then shp.Cells("Width").Formula = "1.0": shp.Cells("Height").Formula = "1.0 ": shp.Characters.CharProps(visCharacterSize) = 12
        VisioApp.Visible = True
    End If
Exit For
Next
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it actually not run, or just seems to do nothing? If you unconditionally exit the for, the script will only run on the first shape.

Comment: Why are you using GetObject? That function is used to open non-Visio files, not to open VSDM files. Are you sure the code actually runs?

Comment: yess after removing Exit for the code is running thank you so much